# Derivative of $(5x-2)^3$

Tags: derivatives

How is the derivative of $(5x-2)^3$ equal to $15(5x-2)^2$ and not $3(5x-2)^2$. According to $\frac{df}{dx} = nx^{n-1}$, it has to be $3(5x-2)^2$ right. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $$\frac{d}{dx} x^n = n x^{n - 1}$$ only applies to *pure* powers of $x$. $5x - 2$ is not a pure power of $x$, so this does not apply. The chain rule is necessary here; the derivative of the inner function ($5x - 2$) is $5$ here, accounting for the additional factor.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
By the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) we have that 
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x).$$

In your question the answer would be $3(5x-2)^2$ if you were taking the derivative with respect to $5x-2$, but you are not, instead you are taking the derivative with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You simply forgot to remember using the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(5x-2)^3 = 3(5x-2)^2 \frac{d}{dx}(5x-2) =3(5x-2)^2 \cdot 5 = \boxed{15(5x-2)^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the rule:

$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)^n)=n f'(x)f(x)^{n-1}$, where $f(x)=5x-2$, and $n=3$, so $f'(x)=5$

Combining all of this we have:

$\frac{d}{dx}((5x-2)^3)=(3)(5)(5x-2^{3-1})=15(5x-2)^2$